# How do I convert (3,) numpy vector to (2,2,3) matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I have a following numpy array with the shape `(3,)`

```
a = np.array([2,3,4])
```

How can I convert this vector to the shape of `(2,2,3)` array, i.e.

```
np.array([[[2,3,4],[2,3,4]],[[2,3,4],[2,3,4]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) will roll it that way:

```
np.resize(a, (2,2,3))
```

Or just multiply:

```
np.ones((2,2,3), dtype=a.dtype) * a
```

Comment: Thank you very much, wim! That works like a charm :)